# A simple container structure

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Coming from mobile programing I get used to create some parent hidden view, and position inside it subviews. Trying to do the same with `html/css/Bootstrap`.

Say I already layout some cover background photo :

```
  <div class="openBackContainer">
         <img  src="images/Back.png" alt="l" />
  </div>
```

Now, I would like to create some squared hidden container in the middle of this cover, which has a title and a button to upload photos :

[image]

As you can see I want to add a "virtual/hidden" container in the middle of the cover, then inside align a title and button.
(later this button will use a bootstrap class)

What would be a good practice to create this container inside a cover photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a container that takes 100% of the page and set its background image for your cover.
Then you can use `flex` to center your inner div - it will be transparent by default.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.txt{
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.hidden button {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hidden">
    <div class="txt">Upload Photos</div>
    <button>+</button>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: T H A N K S ! out of curiosity why do you insert the photo inside the CSS and not inside the html ? is it a good practice ?

Comment: Yes, it helps you stretch the image as a cover image and it also doesn't mess up your layout and other elements inside the container

Comment: trying to load my own back image which worked before, not its not, doing it instead your link: background-image:url("images/Back.png");

Comment: Seems OK, it should be the same path as the img `src` path. Make sure the path is correct